# Rake FileList—clean Directory, exclude subdirectory

Tags: ruby, rake, buildr, fileutils, filelist

I am quiet new to ruby, rake, buildr and of course to FileUtils and FileList.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
+root
|-dir1
|+dir2
||-dir not to delete
||-dir3
|-dir4
…
```

After the clean, everything that should be left over is:

```
+root
|+dir2
||-dir not to delete
```

Right now I am trying that:

```
clean do
  FileList[_(:root) + "/**/*"]
    .exclude(_(:dir not to delete))
    .each do |file|
    puts file
  end
end
```

that »puts«

```
root/dir1
root/dir2
root/dir/dir3
root/dir4
```

But how can I now actually go over to delete everything accept the »dir not to delete« including inside its parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there might be smarter ways to do this, but you can just substract the relevant files/directories like this:

all files in my config directory:

```
FileList['config/**/**']
=> ["config/application.rb", "config/boot.rb", "config/compass.rb", "config/database.yml", "config/environment.rb", "config/environments", "config/environments/caching.rb", "config/environments/development.rb", "config/environments/production.rb", "config/environments/test.rb", "config/initializers", "config/initializers/formtastic.rb", "config/initializers/omniauth.rb", "config/initializers/secret_token.rb", "config/initializers/session_store.rb", "config/initializers/slim.rb", "config/initializers/typus.rb", "config/initializers/whitelabel.rb", "config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb", "config/locales", "config/locales/de.base.yml", "config/locales/de.formtastic.yml", "config/locales/de.label.yml", "config/locales/de.yml", "config/locales/en.base.yml", "config/locales/en.formtastic.yml", "config/locales/en.label.yml", "config/locales/en.yml", "config/routes.rb", "config/typus", "config/typus/event.yml", "config/typus/highlight.yml", "config/typus/job.yml", "config/typus/location.yml", "config/typus/material.yml", "config/typus/topic.yml", "config/typus/user.yml", "config/whitelabel.yml"]
```

removing all files that are in the locales directory:

```
FileList['config/**/**'] - FileList['config/**/locales/**']
=> ["config/application.rb", "config/boot.rb", "config/compass.rb", "config/database.yml", "config/environment.rb", "config/environments", "config/environments/caching.rb", "config/environments/development.rb", "config/environments/production.rb", "config/environments/test.rb", "config/initializers", "config/initializers/formtastic.rb", "config/initializers/omniauth.rb", "config/initializers/secret_token.rb", "config/initializers/session_store.rb", "config/initializers/slim.rb", "config/initializers/typus.rb", "config/initializers/whitelabel.rb", "config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb", "config/locales", "config/routes.rb", "config/typus", "config/typus/event.yml", "config/typus/highlight.yml", "config/typus/job.yml", "config/typus/location.yml", "config/typus/material.yml", "config/typus/topic.yml", "config/typus/user.yml", "config/whitelabel.yml"]
```

Comment: that does indeed look smarter! I will give it a try!